# PHP form is not inserting value

Tags: php

Hello I have problem with my php code it won't insert value to the database and when it does the value is duplicate.
Here is the php code:

```
if (isset($_GET['addform']))
{
include '../includes/db.inc.php';
try
{
$sql = 'INSERT INTO author SET Author_name = :Author_name, Author_email =:Author_email';
$s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$s->bindvalue(':Author_name', $_POST['Author_name']);
$s->bindvalue(':Author_email', $_POST['Author_email']);
$s->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
$error = 'Error adding submitted author.';
include 'error.html.php';
exit();
}
header ('Location COMP1321/recipes/admin/authors/authors.html.php');
exit();

}
```

And here is the html form

```
<? php include 'index.php' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title><?php html($pageTitle); ?></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1><?php html($pageTitle); ?></h1>

<form action="?addform" method="GET">
<label for="name"> Name: <input type="text" name="Author_name" id="Author_name"></label>
<br/>
<label for="email"> Email: <input type="text" name="Author_email" id="Author_email" ></label>
<br/>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php html($id); ?>">
<input type="submit" value="<?php html($button); ?>">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea what went wrong here?

Comment: Your form method is `get`, but you try to access `$_POST` values.

Answer (score -1):

In your HTML code:
`<form action="?addform" method="GET">`

You are using **GET** as form method

And in your PHP code:

`$s->bindvalue(':Author_name', $_POST['Author_name']);`

`$s->bindvalue(':Author_email', $_POST['Author_email']);`

you are using **POST**

Try using same method to submit form from html code and get value in PHP code